# Stuck on trying to customize a stackdriver's log enitity via google-fluentd.conf

Tags: logging, google-compute-engine, fluent, stackdriver

Here's my config file:

```
@include config.d/*.conf

<source>
  @type prometheus
  port 24231
</source>
<source>
  @type prometheus_monitor
</source>

<match fluent.**>
  @type null
</match>

<filter **>
  @type add_insert_ids
</filter>

<filter **>
  @type record_transformer
  enable_ruby
  <record>
    logging.googleapis.com/labels foo=bar
    severity info
  </record>
</filter>

<match docker>
  @type google_cloud
  buffer_type file
  buffer_path /var/log/google-fluentd/buffers
  buffer_chunk_limit 512KB
  flush_interval 5s
  disable_retry_limit false
  retry_limit 3
  retry_wait 10
  max_retry_wait 300
  num_threads 8
  use_grpc true
  partial_success true
  enable_monitoring true
  monitoring_type prometheus
</match>
```

As you see, it's quite the same as a default version, but with a few tweaks.

Esp, extra `<filter>` state, when I'm trying to add severity and a label to the log output, but nothing seems to change.
When did I mistake? I followed the official doc, btw.

Thank you in advance